# Strange behavior of base function

Tags: c#

I have ObservableCollection witch can hold two different types `FirstDerivedType` and `SecondDerivedType`. Both of them hold reference on  `Data`. And the main question is why when I am creating instance of the `PlotModel` in constructor `FirstDerivedType()`

```
Data.PlotModel = new PlotModel();
```

it's works well. But when i am creating instance of `PlotModel` in `base.Draw(Data.PlotModel);` i get `null` in `DataContext`. Why?

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new CurrentViewModel();
    }
}
public class CurrentViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<BaseType> items;

    public ObservableCollection<BaseType> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.items;
        }

        set
        {
            this.items = value;
        }
    }

    public CurrentViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<BaseType>();
        Items.Add(new FirstDerivedType (17));
        Items.Add(new FirstDerivedType (100));
        Items.Add(new FirstDerivedType (50));
        Items.Add(new FirstDerivedType (120));
    }
}

public class Data:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public PlotModel PlotModel { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged!=null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}

public abstract class BaseType
{
    public virtual void Draw(PlotModel PlotModel)
    {
        PlotModel = new OxyPlot.PlotModel(); //do not Working
        LineSeries LS= new LineSeries();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {

            LS.Points.Add(new DataPoint(i,rnd.Next(1,100)));
        }
        PlotModel.Series.Add(LS);
        PlotModel.InvalidatePlot(false);
    }
}

public class FirstDerivedType : BaseType
{
    public FirstDerivedType(int ID)
    {
        Data = new Data();
        //Data.PlotModel = new PlotModel(); //Working
        Data.ID = ID;
        base.Draw(Data.PlotModel);
    }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

public class SecondDerivedType : BaseType
{
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: This code is part of WPF application. DataContext is property where i need to place data for binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case which is not working, you are not setting the property `PlotModel` of the instance of type `Data`, you are just setting the value of the method parameter `PlotModel` to a new instance of `PlotModel`. Note that `Data.PlotModel` is still null.

This line here:

```
public virtual void Draw(PlotModel PlotModel)
{
    PlotModel = new OxyPlot.PlotModel(); //do not Working
```

assigns a new instance to the parameter `PlotModel` of the method `Draw`, **NOT** the property `PlotModel` of the instance `Data`. It does not affect the instance `Data` which holds the property `PlotModel`. This line:

```
base.Draw(Data.PlotModel);
```

will not result in the property `Data.PlotModel` changing if the method parameter is reassigned in the `Draw` method.

Try renaming `Draw` to `CreatePlotModel` and then do like this:

```
public virtual PlotModel CreatePlotModel()
{
    var model = new OxyPlot.PlotModel();
    LineSeries LS= new LineSeries();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {

        LS.Points.Add(new DataPoint(i,rnd.Next(1,100)));
    }
    model.Series.Add(LS);
    model.InvalidatePlot(false);
    return model;
}
```

Then assign `PlotModel` property of data: `Data.PlotModel = base.CreatePlotModel()`

Answer (score 1):

Calling a virtual method from a constructor is dangerous.
See more information in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8e39b8h(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: This seems not to be an answer, but a comment.

Comment: Also, thats cpp, the question is about c#. :)

Comment: Agree that should be a comment but it is indeed for C#